# What is SLIP good for?

Tags: ip, ppp

I read a bit about [SLIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Line_Internet_Protocol) in few places, and from what I understand, the goal of this protocol is to allow the transfer (or encapsulation) of IP packets between hosts over a serial line.

But I don't understand - why not just pass the IP packets as they are? Why do we need these END flags to indicate an end of the packets?

Comment: SLIP is obsolete. It is historical trivia the is not applicable to modern business networking. Unfortunately, that is off-topic here.

Comment: This question may be a better fit over at [retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/), which dabbles in historical artifacts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SLIP was an early protocol (mid-1980s) for running IPv4 over a serial line. It was very cumbersome due to both sides requiring identical configuration and compatible SLIP versions.

It was succeeded by PPP in 1994 which enables the passing of parameters between partners and supports many more protocols and options in a downward-compatible way.

When using a serial interface which effectively transfers a byte stream, a protocol for rudimentary data-link-layer (L2) functionality is required: at the very least you require some kind of framing, where data starts and ends. Without framing, missing a single byte from a transmission causes the entire link to malfunction - the receiver has no idea where the next frame (or packet) starts.

SLIP didn't do that much on L2 which resulted in cumbersome and partially instable operation. PPP provides a *lot* more setup for the interface and it is much easier and robust to use as a result.

In the OSI model, both SLIP and PPP belong to the data link layer and use byte-stream serial links as physical layer.

Comment: you mean that by just taking IP packets one after the other, there is no way for the receiver to recognize the boundaries between them?

Comment: Yes, exactly. There's a byte stream and you need to make head or tails of it.

Comment: so is this also part of the Ethernet protocol for example?

Comment: Ethernet variants use loss of carrier or IDLE symbols on the channel to indicate end-of-data. The beginning of a frame is indicated by the start-of-frame sequence following the preamble (that also synchronizes the receiver to bit and byte boundaries).

Comment: Serial links using RS-232 already provide bit-level and byte-level synchronization so that isn't required within SLIP or PPP. HDLC is an alternative L2 protocol for 'bare' serial interfaces.

Comment: Didn't understand your last comment - the problem is to mark the boundaries between one IP packet to another, isn't it? RS-232 doesn't help us with that..

Comment: Right - that's why you need a protocol and can't just send bare packets. I was trying to point out the difference that Ethernet additionally provides bit and byte level synchronization.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129466/discussion-between-yoavklein-and-zac67).